# HTML5 Video play, pause and rewind on scroll and click not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm working on a banner which needs user interaction. The ad starts with video once you scroll down/Click the video should start playing and pause after 2 seconds time. Again if you scroll down video will start playing from same paused position for 2 secs. If user scroll up video will get rewind from same point in 2 secs interval.

My problem over here. How to disable click and scroll Up/Scroll Down when video start to play. Moreover video also not pausing in 2 secs exactly. Complete code in codepen.

http://codepen.io/harshagopalkrishna/pen/gLBbmb

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
//var log = document.getElementById('log');
var intervalRewind;
//var startSystemTime;
//var startVideoTime;

$(video).on('play',function(){
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});

$(video).on('pause',function(){
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    //clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});

$(video).on('ended',function(){
    // this only happens when t=duration (not t==0)
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
    //alert("video ended");
});

$("#closeButton").click(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    video.pause();
});

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll click', function(event){

    var curTime = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
    var stopTime = Math.floor(2000);

    if ( ( event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) && event.type != "click" ) {
        //alert(stopTime);
        rewind(1.0);

        setTimeout(function(){
            clearInterval(intervalRewind);
            video.pause();
        },stopTime);

    }

    else {
        $("#video-play").hide();
        clearInterval(intervalRewind);
        video.playbackRate = 1.0;
        if (video.paused) {video.play(); }
        setTimeout(function(){
            video.pause();
        },stopTime);            
    }               
});


function rewind(rewindSpeed) {    
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
    var startSystemTime = new Date().getTime();
    var startVideoTime = video.currentTime;

    intervalRewind = setInterval(function(){
        video.playbackRate = 1.0;
        if(video.currentTime == 0){
            clearInterval(intervalRewind);
            video.pause();
        } else {
            var elapsed = new Date().getTime()-startSystemTime;
            video.currentTime = Math.max(startVideoTime - elapsed*rewindSpeed/1000.0, 0);
        }
    }, 30);
}
```